# Buttons display progress

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a project for parent with a newborn Child, where they can progress in their learning taking care of their Child. This will be shown with buttons, and when a stage is complete, it will change the color on that button.

My code so far looks like this:
To change the buttons color to green.

```js
    var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Change diaper</h2>
      <div class="well">
      <input type="button" id="button" value = "Instructed" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>
      <input type="button" id="button" value = "Done with help" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>
      <input type="button" id="button" value = "Done by yourself" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I Click the first button "Instructed" the color change to green (As I want it to). But when I click anyother button, the first button once again goes green and the other goes blue?

How can I fix it so whatever button they click on, will be colored green?

Comment: All of your buttons have the same ID, an ID should be unique for the whole website. Perhaps may be the root of your problems...

Answer (score 0):

You gave every button the same `id` - an id should be identifying, which in this case it isn't. Your code here, takes the first element with the id `button` which is why the first button changes everytime.

Either use different ids for each individual button, or access the clicked element itself through the event-variable.

You also have only one count-variable, which won't work with multiple buttons. Imagine you pressing the first button => `count` is now `1`. You then press the second button, it wouldn't turn green, as `count` is already `1`.

You should probably store that information on the element itself, probably with a `data-count`-attribute.

Here is a working example:

```js
function setColor(element) {
 if(!element.hasAttribute('data-count')){
   element.setAttribute('data-count', 1);
  }
  
  var count = element.getAttribute('data-count');
  
  if(count == 0){
   element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    element.setAttribute('data-count', 1);
  }else{
   element.style.backgroundColor = '#7fff00';
    element.setAttribute('data-count', 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h2>Change diaper</h2>
      <div class="well">
      <input type="button" value = "Instructed" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this)";/>
      <input type="button" value = "Done with help" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this)";/>
      <input type="button" value = "Done by yourself" style= "color:black" onclick="setColor(this)";/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets remove those duplicate ID's, and then we can actually pass the element into the function directly so we don't need to grab it by it's ID.

Then instead of using a `count` variable, we store value on the actual element in a `data` attribute so that it's state is stored on the element itself.

```js
function setColor(element) {
  if (element.getAttribute('data-done') === "0") {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
    element.setAttribute('data-done', "1");
  } else {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
    element.setAttribute('data-done', "0");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Change diaper</h2>
  <div class="well">
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Instructed" style="color:black" onclick="setColor(this)" data-done="0" />
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="Done with help" style="color:black" onclick="setColor(this)" data-done="0" />
    <input type="button" id="button3" value="Done by yourself" style="color:black" onclick="setColor(this)" data-done="0" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Although perhaps the most semantic way would be to use classes and add an event listener:

```js
// Grab all the buttons by their class
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-diaper');

// Loop through the buttons
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  // Assign a click listener to each button
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var el = event.toElement;
    
    // Toggle the "active" class, which changes the button styling
    if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
      el.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
      el.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.btn-diaper {
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.btn-diaper.active {
  background-color: #7fff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Change diaper</h2>
  <div class="well">
    <input class="btn-diaper" type="button" id="button1" value="Instructed" />
    <input class="btn-diaper" type="button" id="button2" value="Done with help" />
    <input class="btn-diaper" type="button" id="button3" value="Done by yourself" />
  </div>
</div>
```